# JS / node.js: Large switch-case blocks vs. function-collection

Tags: node.js, function, switch-statement, case

I've seen on Github a code like this:

```
 switch (type) {
   case 'case1':
     return this.case1();
   case 'case2':
     return this.case2();
   case 'case3':
     return this.case3();
   ...
  default:
    return this.default();
}
```

It contains 25 cases + default case.

I would use different way and pack all functions into an object:

```
var list = {};
list.case1 = function() {
   return /* code */;
};
list.case2 = function() {
   return /* code */;
};
list.case3 = function() {
   return /* code */;
};
// and so on
if(type in list) {
    return list[type]();
} else {
    return this.default();
}
```

You can also dynamically add more cases:

```
if(optionEnabled) {
    list.case4 = function() {
       return /* code */;
    };
    list.case5 = list.case6 = function() {
       return /* code */;
    };
}
```

Well, it can be a bit prettier. My question is:
which way is better if you got a large number of cases and they still can expand?

Important factors are:

- performance
- expandability (in my way it's easier to extend,my code contains the words `case1`, `case2`, `case3` only once each)
- readability and understandability

Answer (score 0):

In the second example, you define your functions inline. Thus, you see the words `case1`, `case2` etc. only once for each. But you can achieve the same result defining inline your functions using `switch/case`:

```
switch (type) {
  case 'case1':
    return function() {
        return /* code */;
    }();
  case 'case2':
    return function() {
        return /* code */;
    }();
  case 'case3':
    return function() {
        return /* code */;
    }();
  ...
 default:
   return function() {
        return /* code */;
    }();
}
```

By the way, when you have to set your "cases" at runtime you have to set your functions into an object.

#### UPDATED

Code correction, thank you to @Artisan72 comment.

Comment: Of course, it makes only sense if the list is only once initialized. But your code is wrong - it returns functions, not values.

Comment: Yes you're right thank you. A couple of parenthesis are missing to have the same scenario of the object example, where you call `return list[type]();`. Likewise we can do `return function() { /* code */; }();`

Comment: In any case, I think that "stacking" functions inside a switch/case statement reduces redability and it's not a good compromise instead of repeating 'caseX' twice. If you need to dynamically add cases, you must go into the object solution. Otherwise I'd prefer the long switch/case (defining functions elsewhere and repeating 'caseX' twice). If for some reason you can't use a switch/case statement, in my opinion, yours is a very good solution. But I think that any workaround not to use switch/case statement will produce a lower performance than V8 with a native switch/case :-)